# Oracle apex - Tabular form calculating display fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-apex, tabular

I have two regions on my page Inserting region and tabular region where are display items from Insert region. Now i need to calcuate two fields in tabular for in separate page item , and after every insert I want to do that calculation again. 
[image]

This is the page, I want to calculate red field * orange for every row (ID),it doesn't depend is it checked or no not. but by black ( ID). Problem is that these are displays fields I cant use apex_application.g_f0.. cause are items are dipslay fields. So how can i loop this calculation .
Thanks !!!!

Comment: Are those columns generated in your SQL? If so, you can just add a new column into your SQL statement, e.g. `SELECT red * orange AS new_column FROM table`